# ListView add more items in Metro apps?

Tags: html, listview, microsoft-metro, winjs

I have a metro application in which I have a Listview and service data contains above 100 items. Initially when am loading listview in my page it has to display only 8 items plus 1 more-related item and later if i click on a more-item it needs add another 9 items to my page and totally it has to show 17 items in my page and need to display more item also like that flow continues.What should I get to get my scenario.Can anyone help me.Below I tried to give u my scenario.
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of solutions -- all depending on the work that you want to undertake. Also, I would suggest that you don't have a "More" button if you can help it -- it's not the best user interaction. Option 2 is going to give you the best experience.

**Option 1**

Use `WinJS.Binding.List` as your data source -- using this you can manipulate it like a JavaScript `Array` (e.g. `push`, `pop` etc). As you add & remove items from the list, the list view will react to those changes.

Full details are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465496.aspx).

**Option 2**

Create a VirtualDataSource derivation that is intimately aware of the ways in which you can request your data, and can offer up a consistent interface to the ListView. This enables your UI to be completely flexible to it's layout, and request enough data to satisfy the available space, while virtualizing the UI elements (better memory/performance), and the data (ensuring only the data *needed* by the user is requested.

Full worked example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh770849.aspx).