# Dynamically add items to listview in windows8

Tags: javascript, html, listview, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ListView add more items in Metro apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783833/listview-add-more-items-in-metro-apps)

As per the below image[First part] I would like to put a tile with text "More" at the end of my list view(created using data from an Array), after clicking on which there should be a popup [as in 2nd part of image] with text box and buttons in my Windows8 application created using HTML/JavaScript.

can any one please help me for this....

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the same question you asked previously, which I answered here:
[ListView add more items in Metro apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783833/listview-add-more-items-in-metro-apps/12792437#12792437)